# Rails routing error Redirect Yahoo instead of routing_error.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem,

When I have an error from Rails instead of the normal error page I'm redirected to Yahoo Page Not Found.

It's not a problem from a special project, I try to create a new project and it's the same thing.

I also tried on Chrome and Firefox and it's the same project.

Any idea ?

Comment: What?Your page redirected to `Yahoo.com`?

Comment: When I use localhost:3000/test (this route doesn't exist) i'm redirected to yahoo or bing.

Comment: Please post your controller code and routes.

Comment: Yeah I use localhost, I did a mistake while writing comment

Comment: It's not a problem from the project, I tried to create a new project and it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's a Yahoo redirection Virus.

Thanks for helping